# Pegar valor da coluna de uma tabela HTML e passar para variável PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Já vi que há bastante exemplo na web de como pegar o valor da coluna de uma tabela `HTML`, como também de passar o valor de uma variável `JavaScript` para o `PHP`. Porém, quando eu estou usando os dois juntos não está dando certo. Já fiz e refiz várias vezes o código, ele agora está desta forma:

### **index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault;
            var codigo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-nome]').data('nome');
            alert(codigo);
        });
    });

<?php
$variavelphp = "<script>document.write(codigo)</script>";
$_SESSION['codigo'] = "Este é Código:  $variavelphp";
?>
</script>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Ação</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>111</td>
            <td data-nome="111">Joaquim Caetano</td>
            <td><a href="ValidaCliente.php"><button class="btn-danger">Pegar Valor do Código</button></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>222</td>
            <td data-nome="222">Maria da Silva</td>
            <td><a href="ValidaCliente.php"><button class="btn-danger">Pegar Valor do Código</button></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Este é o código da página que vou utilizar o valor da sessão criada:

### **ValidaCliente.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$idCliente = $_SESSION['codigo'];
echo $idCliente;
```

Na página `index.php`a mensagem de alerta está correta, porém ao chegar no `ValidaCliente.php` é mostrado somente o texto fixo que é adicionado à sessão e não o código. Vejam nas imagens:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Desde já grato pela ajuda!**

Comment: Você vai ter que usar [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) mano, desse jeito não vai dar certo, porque o PHP carrega antes, só depois que o PHP finaliza a execução, que a página carrega com o JavaScript.

Comment: Completando o que o @JuniorNunes disse acima. Tenha em mente que o PHP é executado no servidor enquanto o Javascript é executado no cliente(browser)

Comment: Bem lembrado, como ainda estou aprendendo a linguagem alguns desses detalhes as vezes termino esquecendo, mas irei ver como posso fazer estes procedimentos aqui para o meu exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**index.php**:

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault;
            var codigo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-nome]').data('nome');
            $.get( "CriaSession.php",{ codigo: codigo});
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Ação</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>111</td>
            <td data-nome="111">Joaquim Caetano</td>
            <td><a href="ValidaCliente.php"><button class="btn-danger">Pegar Valor do Código</button></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>222</td>
            <td data-nome="222">Maria da Silva</td>
            <td><a href="ValidaCliente.php"><button class="btn-danger">Pegar Valor do Código</button></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CriaSession.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

if (isset($_GET['codigo'])){
    $_SESSION['codigo'] = $_GET['codigo'];
}
else {
    $_SESSION['codigo'] = NULL;
}
```

**ValidaCliente.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
$idCliente = $_SESSION['codigo'];
echo $idCliente;
```